# How to fetch sub-collection data from firestore

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection called TripInfo following with user's id and then I have created subcollection with auto generate id for each doc. The problem is I can't fetch the data using the following code:

```
private void checkDataExistingDate() {
    db.collection("TripsInfo").document(UID).collection("Individual_Trip").document()
            .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.getResult().exists()){
                DocumentSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();

                Map<String, Object> map = snapshot.getData();
                for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {

                        Log.d(Tag, "All data"+entry.getValue().toString());

                }

            }

        }
    });
```

Or do I need to store the without subcollection? In Realtime we were using push to generate auto-id, but here I don't know what is the equivalent to create a key after placing the user's id in the document.

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot and indicate the exact data that you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have store userid with uid parameter in TripsInfo collection and also have Individual_Trip as subcollection in 'TripsInfo' collection. you can fetch subcollection like this.

```html
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("TripsInfo")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(
                        new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                        if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid().equalsIgnoreCase(document.getString("uid"))) {
                                            document.getReference()
                                                    .collection("Individual_Trip")
                                                    .get()
                                                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                                            list = task.getResult().toObjects(Individual_Trip.class);
                                                            showListOfRequest();
                                                        }
                                                    })
                                                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                                            hideProgress();
                                                        }
                                                    });

                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid().equalsIgnoreCase(document.getString("uid"))
```

this line is for checking for userid, when you have multiple data in your 'TripsInfo' collection.

you can also use whereEqualTo for that, `FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("TripsInfo")
.whereEqualTo("userId", "uid").get()...`